# Login redirects to previous page even with incorrect info

Tags: magento-1.9, login, redirect

I have "Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in" set to NO as my intention is to point the customer back to the page they were viewing when they login.

This works for the most part, but unfortunately they still get put back to the previous page even when the user/pass is incorrect, with no indication that their login was incorrect, it is only when they manually go back to the login screen is there an error message shown. Correct logins redirect to previous page as intended.

Is this intentional behavior by Magento? Do I require a custom module or extension to fix this error? The ideal scenario is that the customer does not get punted to the previous page until a successful login is placed.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: The default behavior is to keep the customer on the login page when the user/pass is incorrect.

Comment: This behavior works when "Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard" is set to YES. It is only when I set it to NO that it still pushes them to the previous page on incorrect logins.